# Mapping spaces for triples

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A\subset B\subset C$ be cofibrant inclusions. Assume that we know  that for any space $X$ and any $f\colon B\to X$, the natural inclusion of the space of maps $C\to X$ fixed as $f$ on B into the mapping space $C\to X$ fixed as $f$ on $A$ is always a weak equivalence. Is there any necessary and sufficient condition on $(C,B,A)$ that guarantees this?

Initially I thought that this condition is that the inclusion $A\subset B$ is a weak equivalence. But here is an example, where the above property holds, but $A\subset B$ is not an equivalence:

Let $T$ be an open tubular neighborhood of a non-trivial knot $K$ in $S^3$, and $S^1$ be a circle bounding a disc $D^2$ that intersects transversally $K$. Then take $A=S^1$, $B=S^3\setminus T$, $C=S^3$. Note that $C$ is simply connected, thus we can choose $f$ to be constant on $S^1$, but then $B/A$ is contractible. This implies the above property.

Any ideas about the necessary and sufficient condition?

I can show that $B/A$ must be contractible, see discussion below.

Comment: In your example $C$ is the homotopy cofiber of the map from $A\to B$. Are you making this additional assumption in the first paragraph of your question? If so, we can conclude in the general case that $A\to B$ is a cohomology isomorphism in any cohomology theory.

Comment: Thank you for your question, and remark. No, I do not make this assumption. I changed $C$ to $S^3$, so that it's not the cofiber any more.

Comment: John, which $X$ you use to prove your statement?

Comment: I would take $X$ to be the infinite loop space of a spectrum representing a cohomology theory. The point is that if $C$ is the cofiber, then $F(C,X) \to F(B,X) \to F(A,X)$ is a fibration, she $F({-},{-})$ means function space. Your  hypothesis will imply that the map $F(B,X) \to F(A,X)$ is a weak equivalence.

Comment: Actually, a stronger condition holds: $B/A$ must be contractible. Indeed, consider $X=B/A$, and take $f=q\colon B\to B/A$. Then one of the mapping spaces is the space of pointed maps $C/A\to B/A$, and another is the space of maps $C/A\to B/A$ sending $B/A$ identically to itself. Since the first space contains the constant map $C/A\to *\to B/A$, there must exist a map in the second space that is homotopic to it in the first space. As a consequence $B/A$ is contractible.